# Using getStartPositionOfChar (or getEndPositionOfChar) on SVG text element with a white space

Tags: javascript, svg

I am trying to use `getStartPositionOfChar` on a SVG `text` tag that contains only one white space:

**SVG**

```
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="300" height="300">    
   <text id="t"> </text>
 </svg>
```

**JS**

```
var t = document.getElementById('t');
var sp = t.getStartPositionOfChar(0);
```

Although it works fine when the `text` tag has a non-space character, it seems to trim white space, resulting in `IndexSizeError`.

https://jsfiddle.net/tomohiro_1221/7bmefec7/

Is there a workaround for this? I would like to obtain the start position (or end position) when it has only a white space.

Comment: As a workaround try using `&#160;` (non-breaking space) instead of a regular space.

Comment: For those who want to use getStartPositionOfChar on dynamically created text nodes, use `t.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace', 'xml:space', 'preserve')` instead of setAttribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could disable whitespace compression by using xml:space="preserve" (SVG 1.1) or CSS white-space: pre; (SVG 2)

```js
var t = document.getElementById('t');
var sp = t.getStartPositionOfChar(0);
console.log(sp);
```

```css
svg {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="300" height="300">    
   <text id="t"> </text>
 </svg>
```